# Как внести значение базы данных в qtablewidget? python pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
import sys
import subprocess
import struct

class Ui_Form(object):

    def __init__(self):
        object.__init__(self)

    def loadData(self):
        status = self.db.open()
        if status == False:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", self.db.lastError().text(), QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Discard)
        else:
            self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
            self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['id', 'IP_address', 'Время_НСД','Вид_НСД'])
            row = 0
            sql = "SELECT * FROM FAKT"
            query = QtSql.QSqlQuery(sql)
            while query.next():
                self.tableWidget.insertRow(row)
                id = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(0)))
                nome = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(1)))
                surname = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(2)))
                sur = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(3)))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, id)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, nome)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 2, surname)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 3, sur)
                row = row + 1
        #self.db.close()

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(382, 316)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Form)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 319, 201))
        self.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(16)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 270, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.inst)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Code"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Name"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Surname"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Sur"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Load"))
    def inst(self):
        connection = pymysql.connect(
            host='192.168.*.*',
            user='user',
            password='***',
            database='NSD',
            charset='utf8',
            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
        )
        i=0
        mycursor = connection.cursor()
        mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM FAKT')
        row = mycursor.fetchone()
        table=QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        item=QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        while row is not None:
            for key in row:
                ++i
                item=QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setText(str(row[key]))
                table.setItem(0,i,item)
            row = mycursor.fetchone()


if __name__=="__main__":

    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form=QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui=Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Изучаю python совсем немного (простите за корявый код) при изучении баз данных возникла проблема нужно, чтобы значение базы данных занести в таблицу, при этом другая программа с других компьютеров регистрирует события в базе данных, использую mysql, при выполнении кода ячейки не заполняются

Comment: `при выполнении кода ячейки не заполняются ` какого кода, в `loadData`? Вы пробовали добавить `print` по всему коду (или включить отладку) и смотреть выполняется ли код как задумывалось? Плюс, мне непонятно как у вас получилось бы объединить код из `pymysql` и `QtSql.QSqlQuery`, т.к.`QSqlQuery` работает с `Qt`'шным соединением и знать не должен про `pymysql`. Т.е. вы либо используйте `pymysql` и через выполняете `SELECT`, заполняя таблицу, либо используйте `QtSql`, для этого через `Qt` делать подключение, пример: https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/sql-connecting.html

Answer (score 1):

Совет. откажитесь от QTableWidget. На первый взгляд может показаться что это просто, но геммороя больше. Лучше всего сразу разберитесь с QTableView + QSqlTableModel/QSqlQueryModel/... код будет на порядок понятнее и проще.

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtSql/QSqlTableModel.html

Но если все же хотите изобретать велосипеды, то

https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-table/

Что касается конкретно вашего кода, то

1. проверьте что соединение с БД устанавливается (см. isOpen для БД)
2. Запрос успешно отрабатывает и возвращает данные (см. query.lastError)
3. заполняются ячейки в имеющихся строках (для начала попробуйте перед заполнением setRowCount(1000) поставить)